# Cant connect to remote server: Tunnel error - could not open port forwarding to SSH channel

Tags: mysql, database, remote-access

I have a VPS on which I am running MySql, I have created a user and provided all access by using:

```
mysql> CREATE USER 'root1'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'some_pass';
mysql> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root1'@'%'
    ->     WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

I then went onto a remote PC and attempted to connect to the database using:
http://gyazo.com/4bfc541668170d4cdbac01037f3a0c51
When I run this from workbench, I get the following error:
http://gyazo.com/6e76caf3134366b4fabbca58df016916

I am stuck on how I should fix this, initially I thought it was a port forwarding problem for port 3306 however, I have been informed that this does not matter for VPS's.

Comment: `mysql> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;` ?

Comment: tried it still get the error

Comment: Shouldn't the MySQL host name be `localhost`, assuming it's the same host as the SSH server?

Comment: I get the same error, and also, I checked on the sql client using the show variable hostname command and it returned rocket

Comment: Only thing I can suggest now is opening up the SSH tunnel manually (`ssh -f rahul@<IP WENT HERE> -L 3306:rocket:3306 -N`) and trying to connect, even if it's just via telnet (`telnet localhost 3306`). Keep in mind I'm only guessing at the local port. It may not be `3306`

Answer (score 1):

In case others come along, I'm getting the same problem, and it is related to the server not accepting local tcp connections.

Test it out by opening a shell on the target server, and trying something like mysql --protocol=tcp -u user -p

It could be that you've got a firewall that is blocking them, or more likely that your server.cnv has a bind statement that isn't localhost, and hence, doesn't accept tcp connections from localhost.